# Cant download apache httpd 2.4

Tags: apache, download

Im trying to download apache hhtpd from http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/win32/ or any other mirror but i cant find the .msi installer. i am doing something wrong?? i find the httpd-2.2.25-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi  here http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/win32/?C=M;O=D but this is not the latest verion of httpd.

Comment: Well, your first link includes this: "The Apache HTTP Server Project itself does not provide binary releases of software..."  So, you're going to have to look elsewhere.  The page to which you linked has a list of suggestions.  Also, this question is *very* off-topic for a programming site.

Comment: Ok, but what happend? did they stop providing the installers?

Comment: My guess is that they did stop, but y'know what?  It doesn't make any difference.  You're going to have to find an installer elsewhere.